# React - dangerouslySetInnerHTML being displayed as plain text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I've created a React app that displays job postings. When I click on a job post in the list, that particular job post's details are displayed.

I'm trying to display the body of the job post in the same way that it has been formatted at the source. To do that, I've tried using the following code:

```
<div id="apply-now" className="apply-section">
    <h3>How to apply.</h3>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: currentJob.description }}></div>
</div>
```

However, when the component is rendered, the content is not formatted and is displayed in plain text without the appropriate formatting.

Here's an example that hasn't been formatted:

> [image: example]

The word `__"Application"__` should be in bold, the website link should be an actual link, as should "Click here for an application form" link.

The data I'm getting back from the API call is the same as above:

> Join us! - We are looking forward to your application via the **"Application"** form Your contact: Ralph Ullmann Telefon: 089/ 5511 333783 https://www.consorsfinanz.de/karrier [Click here for the application form!](https://vonq.io/2Nu2YPC)"

^^ Even above on StackOverflow it works! But I can't get it to work in my app!

I've been tearing my hair out for hours trying to fix this and I can't even understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: So your question is how to style it ?

Comment: @KonstantinModin yes, in the same way that it appears in the quoted text above.

Comment: `__TEXT__` is not html for bold, this is markdown. Either use something to render the markdown correctly, or use some kind of replacement logic to replace `__` attached to the front of a word with `<strong>` and `__` attached to the end of a word as `</strong>`.

Comment: There are a few libraries you could try [react-markdown](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown), [markdown-to-jsx](https://github.com/probablyup/markdown-to-jsx), etc I can't speak for the performance or developer experience of any of them so I wouldn't be able to suggest one.

Comment: Correct, what you receive is [Markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/cheat-sheet/), which is not at all the same as HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an algorithm challenge. Sorry thought it could be done in an elegant way, but regex would be the better option

1. Use regex to match anything inbetween two underscores
2. In each match, replace remove the underscores and wrap each element in `strong` tags

```js
  const mdBoldToStrong = (text) => {
const surroundingUnderscores = new RegExp(/__(.*?)__/g)
return text
  .replace(surroundingUnderscores, (word) => {
    return `<strong>${word.replace(/__/g, '')}</strong>`
  })
  }

console.log(mdBoldToStrong('__Application__'))
console.log(mdBoldToStrong('Text__Application__Text__'))
console.log(mdBoldToStrong('__Text____Application__Text'))
```

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: Would this not wrap every side of the split in strong tags? Given `"Text __Bold__ Text"` you would end up with `"<strong>Text </strong><strong>Bold</strong><strong> Text</strong>"`.

Comment: @JacobSmit You're correct. Looks like this might be a little more challenging than it seems, sec

Comment: If the bold styling is all that is needed, this should do the trick. if other markdown styling is needed you may still want to look at a markdown parser of some form.